# Execute Queries in Oracle with Dynamic input in where clause

Tags: oracle

I have DEPT(DEPTNO, DNAME, LOC) table with some data.

I would like to query for all departments with search key as DNAME.

I am trying something like below, but not working. Can anyone please suggest me. I am pretty new to oracle.

```
dynamicDeptName varchar2(30):= 'cco';
execute immediate 'select * from dept where dname like '%' || dynamicDeptName || '%'
```

Comment: smth like this `execute immediate 'select * from dept where dname like ''%' || 'dynamicDeptName' || '%'''`?

Answer (score 2):

1. Use bind variables, it is easier as well as better (more efficient and secure)
2. Single quotes need to be doubled-up inside a single-quoted string.

Example:

```
 execute immediate
   'select * from dept where dname like ''%'' || :dname || ''%'''
   into dept_rec
   using dynamicDeptName;
```

Or use q-quote syntax to avoid need to double-up the quotes:

```
execute immediate 
  q'[select * from dept where dname like '%' || :dname || '%']'
   into dept_rec
  using dynamicDeptName;
```

Comment: You cannot put a bind variable inside of a string literal.  I think you need to tweak your answer.

Comment: @MatthewMcPeak Thanks, tweaked.